# CSS - how to apply styles to first elements in a static generated list

Tags: html, css

I have a list like this that Asciidoctor generate for me

> ```
> <ul class="sectlevel1">
>   <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
>   <li><a href="#">Certification Process</a>
>   <ul class="sectlevel1">
>     <li><a href="#">Stage 1: OnBoard</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Stage 2: Developing The Connector</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Stage 3: Certify</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Stage 4: Publish</a></li>
>     <li><a>Release Re-Certification</a></li>
>   </ul>    
>  <li><a href="#">Development</a>
> </ul>
> ```

http://postimg.org/image/a1d9qzp2p/  IMAGE

I want to put some style in the first level elements of the list (Introduction,Certification Process, Development), which is the apropiate selector to do this?.

I am only able to edit all the  `<li>'s`

Also, I cannot change the HTML, cause is what asciidoctor generate for me.

Thanks in advance, Juan

Comment: just look at CSS selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors and out this one >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to wrap the whole thing in a parent and address the structure via that.

```css
.container > ul > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="sectlevel1">
    <li><a href="#">Introduction</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Certification Process</a>
      <ul class="sectlevel1">
        <li><a href="#">Stage 1: OnBoard</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Stage 2: Developing The Connector</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Stage 3: Certify</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Stage 4: Publish</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Release Re-Certification</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Development</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. this could help but is not solving my problem, I want to edit the styles so the first level titles are bigger or stronger. 

Thanks a lot I'll implement this for a quick fix

Comment: @JuanMartinDesimoni I don't see the issue? I've updated the above example with a minor css change.